# PDF size difference between IE and Microsoft Edge Browser

Tags: windows-10, pdf, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, print-to-pdf

I am trying to print to download one PDF document from EDGE and IE browser on Windows 10 machine by selecting printer as Microsoft print to PDF.
Document size coming as 101 MB when printing from EDGE while printing from IE size is 33 MB.

Why is there a PDF size difference (almost thrice) between Edge and IE? Is it due to EDGE or Microsoft print to PDF?

Due to this PDF size, the printer is taking more time to print the PDF.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: IE11, by default does not have the ability to open PDF files while Edge, can open PDF files using it's built-in PDF reader.  We need more information.

Comment: @Ramhound, what information do you need? please elaborate.i will share if available.

Answer (score 0):

IE is from Microsoft, dating initially from 1995
(which is 26 years ago), while Edge is relatively new from Chrome.

Without examining the two PDF files I can't give a solid answer.

The likeliest answer is that IE missed out on newer
features, so omitting while printing features that it doesn't
recognize, features that belong to the latest versions of HTML
and CSS.

Because IE did so much less, the resulting PDF was so much smaller.

Comment: Thanks for replying.Generated Pdf has also some color images.can this be the cause for increase in pdf size?